# Connecting MySQL to php files (pear error)

Tags: php

```
Warning: require_once(book/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\book\book.php on line 48

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'book/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR;;/book;/book/classes;/book/pear/PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\book\book.php on line 48
```

I added this to the file:

```
require_once('book/autoload.php');
include_path('C:\xampp\php\PEAR;;/book;/book/classes;/book/pear/PEAR');
```

This is very rudimentary, but it's still not working. Have mercy, this is my first php project.

Comment: It seems the autoload.php file is in the same directory as book.php. if so you should only do `require_once('autoload.php');`

Comment: thanks a lot. i have this pear related error next. Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'DB.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR;;/book;/book/classes;/book/pear/PEAR;;;/functions;/functions/basic;/functions/html;/functions/forms;/functions/database') in C:\xampp\htdocs\book\functions\database.php on line 4

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
require_once('book/autoload.php');
```

and must check that your folder path is correct.

Comment: thanks,  Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'DB.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR;;/book;/book/classes;/book/pear/PEAR;;;/functions;/functions/basic;/functions/html;/functions/forms;/functions/database') in C:\xampp\htdocs\book\functions\database.php on line 4 any idea how to solve this? i am sure this is a folder path error , but i just don't know where to look. i can't find db.php in xampp/folder path/pear

Comment: I am not sure about your file folder structure but check if there are any problem regarding your defined file path like / and ../